# Snap App Icon Missing On App Side Menu PopOS

Tags: ubuntu, snap

I have the latest version of Pop!_OS installed, and I used the SnapStore to install Microsoft Visual Studio Code, and everything was fine until today when I rebooted and found my app icon on the drawer to be invisible. The application just works fine.

Here is the preview:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. I have many problems with Snap apps, and I wonder if this is happening for everyone else? For example, after installation, snap apps don't show up under the menu until I add the env path to `/snap/bin/` but when I do that PopOS tells me no such directory exists (when I view the path variable in cmd) but when I `cd` into it, the folder perfectly exists.

Answer (score 0):

The icons you see on the apps menu are edited through their corresponding .desktop file. What I did in my case was:

1. right click on the icon and click show detail, this will bring up the app store.
2. In the search section the name of the file creating that icon should be written.
   (In your case it will likely be code.desktop)
3. search for code.desktop using your file manager. Open the file with a text editor. There you should see a line:

   Icon=com.visualstudio.code

If the name is different or missing, try changing to that.
If that does not work, then maybe the actual image is missing. In that case you can add the image again to the directory:

```
/usr/share/pixmaps
```

link to image:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqi2F.png
```